# changing DOM of page after APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_LANG

Tags: oracle-apex

first here's my application **Globalization** config :
[image]

NOTE : I have 2 languages in my application . the main one is **English** and the other one is **Farsi**.

If I change the language of application by an application process , the HTML DOM of page doesn't change correctly . I mean as you see in the picture , the language has changed and the `apex_util.get_session_lang` shows the right value but in the DOM of page , the `lang` parameter and `dir` has not changed !

[image]

I review the XLIFF file of application and the `dir` and `lang` are defined correctly but how could them not change after switching language in DOM of page? What makes this bug happen ?

more details : this is the parts of my application process related to changing language

```
    IF nvl(apex_util.get_session_lang, 'en-us') = 'en-us' OR
       apex_util.get_session_lang = 'en' THEN
      BEGIN
        apex_util.set_session_lang('fa');

      END;
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        apex_util.set_session_lang('en-us');
      
      END;
    END IF;
```